# Why is Flask making me put @app.route("/interior.html") in route instead of @app.route("/interior")

Tags: python, html, flask

I am building a website with a booking page that requires me to put the data into a database so I am using python Flask app.

I know that in the @app.route I am only supposed to put @app.route("/exterior") however, whenever I try it using this method I get 404 Page Not Found.  Instead I have to put @app.route("/exterior.html").  This is the only way it will work.  I believe I have all the correct libraries and I have defined everything correctly; but, it only works if I put .html in the @app.route.

I have researched @app.routes and it only tells me the correct method which I know is @app.route("/exterior"); however, the only thing that works is @app.route("/exterior.html").  If anyone can tell me why this is happening that would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
import os

from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session
from datetime import datetime

# Configure application - turn this file into a Flask application -
app = Flask(__name__)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded -
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///bookings.db")


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("/index.html")

@app.route("/index.html")
def indexpage():
    return render_template("/index.html")

@app.route("/exterior.html")
def exterior():
    return render_template("exterior.html")


@app.route("/interior")
def interior():
    return render_template("interior.html")

if __name__ == 'main':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

As you can see this is resulting me having to use two routes to load my index page.  Once for when I initially run flask and again, so I am able to link to the pages in my navbar.

It's also not the correct method and it bothers me that I am not able to do it correctly.  Please advise.

Here is my file directory:

```
project
    static
        pics
        styles.css
    templates
        index.html
        interior.html
        exterior.html
        about.html
        gallery.html
        layout.html
        booknow.html
    app.py
    bookings.db
    README.md
```

unsure why app.py and bookings are not before static and templates and alphabetically that would make more sense; however, this is how it is displayed.

Comment: are all your html files in the `templates` folder? also, you're missing the `@` on your `app.route("/")` route

Comment: Yes, all of my index files are in the templates folder and labelled .html.  I have made other programs with Flask and an app.py file and it has worked correctly; however, this one does not for some reason.  I've been looking at it for days and can't see anything that differs in any way; but the route will not work unless I include .html in it.  I notice this post has been down voted which isn't great; but was hoping a fresh set of would see something I am not.

Comment: what about the missing the `@` on your app.route("/") route?

Comment: @AudioBaton, unfortunately, that was not the issue.  I guess when I pasted the code the @ was deleted; but the code on app.py was correct.  I never did sort out the issue with the .html in the app route; but it works fine as long as I include it.  My bookings page required data from the users form to be sent to a database and that route worked fine without the html.  That said, the correct way is to not include the .html in the route; but that's the only way this website will function.  After reaching out on many sites and a few days of research, it would have been nice to know why.

Comment: strange. if it were me, I would start from scratch and try to build up each route once at a time and where it goes wrong. sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and actually cut and paste the majority of app.py from a previous app.py that functions correctly and still have the same issue.  It's absolutely baffles me that two weeks later, I still don't know why It functions this way.  The site functions correctly but, is not coded correctly.  After researching for days on end, it surprises me that no-one else has even encountered this problem.  I received a down vote for this question, and it would have been worth it if the issue was discovered.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and made some minor syntax fixes. below is working as normal. perhaps you could copy this and start adding back some of your functionality and see where it goes wrong.

here is the directory structure:

```
test_app/
    app.py
    templates/
        interior.html
        exterior.html
        index.html
```

and here is app.py:

```py
import os

# from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session
from datetime import datetime

# Configure application - turn this file into a Flask application -
app = Flask(__name__)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded -
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
# db = SQL("sqlite:///bookings.db")


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/index/")
def indexpage():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/exterior/")
def exterior():
    return render_template("exterior.html")


@app.route("/interior/")
def interior():
    return render_template("interior.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

this work normally for me. what about you?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to take a look at this.  I cut and pasted the code in and I still cannot get it to work without the .html in the @app.route.  The issue must lie in how my files are positioned in the directory.   I can't get the edit to display in the comment section, so I have changed it in my original code area above.

Comment: your directory structure looks fine to me. I've got no other tips. is this on GitHub?

Comment: Not yet, the site is live now, so I will create a repository for it this week.  Thanks so much for your help, when I saw your changes in the syntax of the app.route I thought for sure that was it.  That said, I created a function called bookings where I used the correct syntax @app.route(/bookings) that works.  The only difference is that it is an actual function through POST that inserts the contact data a user submits into a form. Upon completion it sends them to a success page.  That syntax works fine; however, the app routes that just define the page paths require .html in the route.

Comment: Hi @AudioBaton, the link to the full project on github is below, any advice to fix this issue would be appreciated.  I recently created a new project and had the same issue; so, it has to be something.  I also have issues with the <a href="index.html> links on the pages.  I have to put it like this.  If I put a / in front they will not work. https://github.com/me50/CWhite1/tree/cs50/problems/2022/x/project/site1

Comment: there is a tiny chance I'll be able to spot something, but I will take a look. however, the link you sent is returning 404. is it a public repo?